# GWT checkbox hides/shows widget

Tags: gwt

How to add clickHandler to a gwt checkbox, so that when the checkbox is checked, a listbox is shown and when it is unchecked, the listbox disappears?

Following is what I have so far. When I check the checkbox, the list appears, but when I uncheck it, the listbox does not disappear.

```
VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
ListBox list = new listBox();
list.setVisible(false);
vPanel.add(list);
.....
.....
checkBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() 
{
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
    {
        boolean checked =((CheckBox) event.getSource()).isEnabled();
        if(checked==true)
        {
            list.addItem("a");
            list.addItem("b");
            list.addItem("c");
            list.setVisible(true);
        }
        else if(checked==false)
        {
            componentList.setVisible(false); 
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enabled != checked! (use `isChecked` or `getValue`)

Otherwise, go with Bhat's code and advises.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do it is to do the value changed handler. The user can even use the keyboards to check the checkbox!

```
CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
c.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event) {
        componentList.setVisible(event.getValue());

    }
});
}
```

edit -

You should add the items in the list outside. And, depending on the default checkbox value,(checked or unchecked), set the component visible or hidden outside itself in the start.

Comment: great suggestion but for some reason your solution gave error stating that addValueChangeHandler is not applicable to a textbox. I checked the api, and your solution should work...